# Rmarkdown figure captions for math equations

Tags: r, latex, yaml, r-markdown

I would like to have a referable equation in rmarkdown document. What do I need to add to the document to get the numbering and the ability to reference.

I am able to put the equation in but cannot get the reference label to appear. I am also unable to reference in line. Perhaps the yaml needs some more info in it?

```
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
 \gamma= \alpha_(i n) - \beta_(f n+1)#reference (1) doesn't appear-->
 \end{equation}  
 This is a reference for equation \ref{eq:1}. This is not working.
```

**What I want to see:**

```
γ=α(in)−β(fn+1)γ=α(in)−β(fn+1)             (1)
```

This is a reference for Equation 1. This is not working.
**What I see:**

```
γ=α(in)−β(fn+1)γ=α(in)−β(fn+1)
```

This is a reference for Equation . This is not working.

edit: putting screen shots of exact input and output. Added html screen cap.

[here is the yaml header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsMJ6.png)

[Here is a code screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt8Wn.png)

I will post the html output when I get to work today. Thanks for the help!
[post knitr output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyEIL.png)

Comment: It works for me.  Can you share exactly how it appears in the Rmarkdown file, headers and all?

Comment: Cross-referencing equations works with output formats supplied by the bookdown package.

Comment: @DavidKlotz hey I’ve added some screen shots. I think it might be a yaml issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] as text, not as image(s).

Comment: Exactly, include the whole code, including YAML R packages, chunk options, etc.
Since you had tagged this as a latex issue, I assumed you were knitting a PDF.  But now you've added this is actually for an HTML file, which might behave slightly differently.

Comment: I understand guys. I'll get something together this week and sow the html issue with full code. The pdf version works fine.